# Переопределение стандартной анимации material компонентов

Tags: angular, angular-material

Подскажите как переопределить анимацию перехода для mat-vertical-stepper и можно ли это сделать вообще?

Comment: ....нет, нельзя

Comment: @overthesanity на самом деле можно, но тот способ который я нашел не очень нравится, скорей всего это должно делаться как-то проще через директивы. Я сделал вот так MatVerticalStepper.decorators[0].args[0].animations[0] = trigger('name', [...])

Comment: > `на самом деле можно` - нет, нельзя. это не CSS анимации, а то что ты видишь в свойстве `decorators` - это только в JIT моде

Comment: @overthesanity ну мне тоже не нравится как это выглядит в коде, однако оно работает, причем работает только если присвоить новое значение до объявления компонента, думаете плохое решение?

Comment: нет, смотри, анимации компилируются в оптимизированный JS код до рантайма (АОТ), ты не можешь их реплейсить (к сожалению). Свойство, которое ты видишь - `decorators` - это свойство добавляет декоратор `Component` только в девелопмент моде, в продакшене этого свойства нету, потому что в продакшене нету декораторов

Comment: @overthesanity спасибо, что-то не проверил сразу в проде